# Jupyter notebook input field appearsin wrong place

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

In a Jupyter notebook, I run the following

```
print("The input field should appear below this line")
input()
```

I expect to get the line of text, followed by an input field. But sometimes I get the opposite. How can I force it to appear in the correct order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `print` function sends text to the system's standard out buffer.  The system then decides when to push what is in the buffer to the front end.  In your case this is occassionally occurring after the `input` request.  You can tell the system "push the output *right now*" by adding `flush=True` as a key word argument to the `print` function.

```
print("The input field should appear below this line", flush=True)
input()
```

Also, you can have your `input` print a line of text as well.

```
input("The input field appear next to this line: ")
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the flush kwarg doesn't seem to have any effect for me.